# Populating a circular double linked list with a txt file

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I'm given a txt file named `circle.txt`. This txt file consists of names and shirt numbers like

```
Cameron 1
David 2
Dorothy 3
Heather 4
```

etc... to 100

So I have to do a project based on the game count-to-oust and one part of the project requires one to create a circular double linked list
using the `void createGame(char* gameFile, int numOfPlayers);` function for the specified number of players so that each link represents a player. Then I have to Set the names and shirt numbers for the players based on values read in from the file. So my header file which has all the functions looks like

countOust.h

```
#ifndef CountOust_h
#define CountOust_h

struct listNode
{
    int hName; //represents numbers in file
    char data[15]; // represents name in file
    struct listNode *next;
    struct listNode *prev;

};
typedef struct listNode sNode;

void createGame(char *gameFile, int numOfPlayers);
//void traverseFwd(sNode *list);
//void insertAt(sNode *list, sNode *player);
//void lRemove(sNode *player);
//void traverseBwd(sNode *list);
//void startGame();

#endif
```

Some functions are commented out because the main focus is on the `createGame` function.

So I have tried populating the link in my `countOust.c` list using `fopen` and a for loop with `fscanf`. I've tried something like

countOust.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "CountOust.h"

void createGame(char *gameFile, int numOfPlayers)
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(gameFile, "r");

   // head = (struct sNode *)malloc(sizeof(sNode);

    fscanf(f, "%s %d", head->data, &head->hName);

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers - 1; i++)
    {


    }


    fscanf(f, "%s %d", tail->data, &tail->hName);


}
```

^This gives an error because its brainstorming code

I need an fscanf which will contain a string and integer representing the names in the files and the numbers in the file.

I need to set the
malloc space for a node, and the node should have a name number reference to next node and a reference to the prev node. Then I need to set the the name and number and then set the pointer for prev and next nodes.

So how would I create a circular double linked list and populate a txt file for the player names and shirt numbers using fscanf, malloc, referencing the nodes from my header file struct, to create a circular double linked list off a txt file?

Comment: Have you searched for "circular linked list," and tried to implement something? There are plenty of examples available online. Do that and if you're still having trouble, post your linked list code and explain what problem you're having. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `gamefile` contains the name of your `circle.txt` file, your `fscanf()` call will only read numbers as it's currently written.  You'll need to add something to read the names as well.

`fscanf(f, "%s %d", args...)` would be a good starting point.